# Return end index of a 2D Vector

Tags: c++, indexing, row, 2d-vector

For instance I create a 2D Vector (1000x3) as:

```
vector<vector<float>> Vector (1000, vector<float>(3))
```

A function then stores 3D points into the vector (not necessarily 1000 points but less than 1000). How should I get the index of last row in the Vector that I created?

I figured out a method called as "end" defined in vector class but don't know the syntax.

Also some may say that I can trace the index of last point stored in the vector, for example:

```
Vector[i][j] = value;
```

But I need this data in other functions, so returning this index all the time doesn't seem as good option to me.

Comment: Create a 1D vector instead and wrap index access!

Comment: It would have been better if you created these large vectors on heap.

Comment: @Cool_Coder Nah, that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Its not related to the question, just a suggestion.

Comment: @Cool_Coder it is a **bad** suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Since each row is a 3D point and so will definitely have 3 elements, an `std::vector` isn't an appropriate type. I would perhaps use a `std::array<float, 3>` or a `struct` with members `x`, `y`, and `z` for the inner type.

It seems that you don't actually want 1000 points in your vector. Maybe you're doing it to avoid reallocations later on? In that case, you should use `Vector.reserve(1000);`. This will reserve memory for the points without actually adding them. Then you can add your points using `emplace_back`, `push_back` or any other mechanism.

Then, to get an iterator to the last point in the vector, you can do either `std::end(Vector) - 1` or `Vector.end() - 1`. If you had kept it as you had it, where there were always 1000 points in the vector, this would have given you an iterator to the 1000th point (even if you hadn't assigned any useful values to it yet).

Comment: Thanx for the input. Yes you are right. I created space for 1000 points because I didn't want reallocation after each push_back. But how do I declare the vector when I user Vector.reserve (1000). There should be some declaration that the vector contain 3 columns (even though I know there is nothing like columns). So, can you tell me how to declare the vector?

Comment: If you have a `struct` called `Point`: `std::vector<Point> Vector;`. If you want to use `std::array`: `std::vector<std::array<float, 3>> Vector;`. Then on the next line you call `Vector.reserve(1000);`.

Comment: 'Then, to get an iterator to the last point in the vector, you can do either std::end(Vector) or Vector.end()' - is actually past the last point.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't initialize it with 1000 elements. Just leave it empty and use Vector.push(...) to add new points, the vector will grow automatically.

Then the last index is:

```
Vector.size() - 1
```

Or if you insist on doing so, you can put it in a class and add a member to store the size.

```
struct PointVector {
    vector<array<float, 3>> Vector;
    int size;
    PointVector() : Vector(1000, {0, 0, 0}), size(0) { }
};
```

Comment: Thanx for the input. I initialized space to store 1000 points because otherwise after each push_back, there would have been a reallocation. Although I will check with your second advise.